# Can I use both "a/an" and "the" to point out same thing?

Tags: grammar, articles

How can I use the indefinite article "a/an" to point out something and, to accomplish the same thing, use the definite article "the"?

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide a little more context? An example would do the job.

Comment: While reading a book, I have seen the usage of article "a" for an animal. In the next few lines, article "the" is used to point out same animal again. So, I want to know that how can we use articles while writing a paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic difference between the indefinite (*a/an*) and the definite(*the*) article is literally in the name: definition.

If you're introducing an object/animal/person in your speech for the first time and this object has no specific features, then it's [indefinite](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and).

I'll give you an example

> I was driving down my street when a deer walked onto the road.

Now that you have introduced it, your reader/listener know there is a deer on the scene, so if you mention that same deer, you use the [definite](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/definite-article) article

> The deer ran into the side of my car and I had to have it fixed. Luckily, I'm ok.

This is what I could answer with the next-to-zero examples you gave; if it is a more specific case I'll modify the answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to Dictionary.com a definition for the word ARTICLE is described as:  #**5. Grammar. any member of a small class of words, or, as in Swedish or Romanian, affixes, found in certain languages, as English, French, and Arabic, that are linked to nouns and that typically have a grammatical function identifying the noun as a noun rather than describing it. In English the *definite article* is the, the *indefinite article* is a or an, and their force is generally to impart specificity to the noun or to single out the referent from the class named by the noun.**

So using that definition in regards to your example of reading a book and seeing both "a/an" and "the" used to reference the same animal; lets say the sentances are:
A cat walked into the room.
The cat walked into the room.

*a/an* refers to any cat in general, where as *the* refers to one specific cat.